# Why does TypeScript not want me to assign a className property to a context provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying out TypeScript for the first time and re-configuring a React app (built with create-react-app) to use TS. I'm using function components, and I've implemented a global context (called OrderContext) to wrap around the App in my index.tsx file. Here's the render statement:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <OrderContextProvider className="orderContext" ><App /></OrderContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

That OrderContextProvider is defined in my order-context.tsx file as follows:

```
export function OrderContextProvider(props: any) {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

  const addItem = (item: CartItem) => {
    setCart((prev) => { return { ...prev, item } });
  };

  return (
    <OrderContext.Provider value={{ cart, addItem: () => undefined }} className={props.className} >{props.children}</OrderContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

My problem is that TypeScript is giving me an error/tooltip on the className property that says the following:

> Type '{ children: any; value: { cart: {}; addItem: () => undefined; };
> className: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> ProviderProps<{ cart: {}; addItem: () => void; }>'.   Property
> 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> ProviderProps<{ cart: {}; addItem: () => void; }>'.ts(2322)

I haven't been able to find any solutions so far and I'm having a hard time parsing what this is trying to tell me. It seems like it's something to do with duck typing since it's inferring the structure of something, but beyond that I'm a bit lost especially with "IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps".

Comment: why you want a className on the provider ? . context in react is just for supplying the data to its subscribed components . It is not going to get rendered anywhere in the UI. So adding a className prop to it doesn't do anything . Regarding the error - it states that context Provider doesn't have a prop called className so you can't add it .

Comment: @Connor Mooneyhan because you are not supposed to pass a `className` prop there. ContextProvider accepts only `value`. If you really want to pass it pass it inside the `value` object.

Comment: @Shyam that's a good point... I should just put the styling on the app component. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Context objects are not DOM element. Provider is just a wrapper function.